# WCF Service with parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using .NET 4.5, C#.NET, WCF Repository Pattern

**WCF Service**

- Customer.svc: `<@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="CustomerService" @>`
- Order.svc: `<@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="OrderService" @>`
- Sales.svc: `<@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="SalesService" @>`
- Products.svc: `<@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="ProductsService" @>`

**Implementing classes**

```
public class CustomerService : Service<Customer>, ICustomerService.cs
{
   private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Customer> _repository;
   public CustomerService(IRepositoryAsync<Customer> repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }
}

public class OrdersService : Service<Orders>, IOrdersService.cs
{
   private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Order> _repository;
   public OrdersService(IRepositoryAsync<Order> repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }
}

public class SalesService : Service<Sales>, ISalesService.cs
{
   private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Sales> _repository;
   public SalesService(IRepositoryAsync<Sales> repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }
}
```

When I run my WCF service, I get a error like there is no empty constructor.
How can I keep these services and implementing classes unchanged and have my WCF service work with those constructors.

Comment: Keyword: `ServiceHostFactory`, for instance see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF itself *requires* the Service Host to have a default/no-argument constructor; the standard WCF service creation implementation does no fancy activation - and it most certainly does *not* handle Dependency Injection! - when creating the Service Host object.

To bypass this default requirement, use a [WCF Service Host *Factory*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) (such as one provided with [Castle Windsor WCF Integration](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/wcf-facility-registration.md)) to create the service and inject dependencies using the appropriate constructor. Other IoCs provided their own integration factories. In this case the IoC-aware service factory creates the service and wires up the dependencies.

To use DI *without* an IoC (or otherwise dealing with a Service Factory), create a no-argument constructor that invokes the constructor with the required dependencies, e.g.

```
public class SalesService : Service<Sales>, ISalesService
{
   private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Sales> _repository;

   // This is the constructor WCF's default factory calls
   public SalesService() : this(new ..)
   {
   }

   protected SalesService(IRepositoryAsync<Sales> repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend use a DI container rather than construct dependencies manually, for instance see http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html.

Comment: @abatishchev Me too: but 'which one' is can of worms and a separate topic. However such DI-without-IoC is an option..

Comment: I used the Castle Windsor WCF facility and it worked really nice. You should definitely give it a try!

Comment: Since I am working on POC project I went with empty constructor for now, but eventually I prefer to do dependency injection using Unity Application Block